# adding dashboard for single application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

My application is single page application built with asp.net core. I recently installed the hangfire in order for putting all the resource intense task in the background so it doesn't clog the server. However i am not able to display dashboard page. Here is the snippets of how I defined the dashboard path in startup. what I am doing wrong here?

```
 app.UseStaticFiles();            
 app.UseRewritePath();
 app.UseAuthentication();

 app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");
 app.UseHangfireServer();

 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: What happens when you navigate to `/hangfire`?

Comment: it goes root of my SPA application.

Comment: What does `app.UseRewritePath();` do?

Comment: oh I guess it will redirect all the call to the index.html. I guess that's why it doesn't not work. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `app.UseRewritePath();` is catching the route before it hits hangfire and sending it to the root of your SPA. The order in which you setup your routes matters.

Reorder your configuration like so:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");            
app.UseRewritePath();
app.UseAuthentication();


app.UseHangfireServer();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```